# Is there a way Rails 3.0.x can default to using Thin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I run the Thin webserver for basically every app in my dev/test environments. When I used Mongrel with Rails 2.x, all I had to type was `script/server` to get it to run the webserver I choose. But with Rails 3, I have to specify Thin every time. Is there a way to get Thin running on my Rails apps by just typing `rails s` instead of `rails s thin`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Rails 3.2rc2, thin is now run by default on invoking `rails server` when `gem 'thin'` is in your Gemfile! Thanks to this pull request: https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/b487f02b13f42c5933aa42193ed4e1c0b90382d7

Works great for me.

Answer (score 21):

Yeah it's possible to do this.

The way the `rails s` command works at the end of the day is by falling through to Rack and letting it pick the server. By default the Rack handler will try to use `mongrel` and if it can't find mongrel it will go with `webrick`. All we have to do is patch the handler slightly. We'll need to insert our patch into the `rails` script itself. Here is what you do, crack open your `script/rails` file. By default it should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

We insert our patch right before the `require 'rails/commands'` line. Our new file should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rack/handler'
Rack::Handler.class_eval do
  def self.default(options = {})
    # Guess.
    if ENV.include?("PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN")
      # We already speak FastCGI
      options.delete :File
      options.delete :Port

      Rack::Handler::FastCGI
    elsif ENV.include?("REQUEST_METHOD")
      Rack::Handler::CGI
    else
      begin
        Rack::Handler::Mongrel
      rescue LoadError
        begin
          Rack::Handler::Thin
        rescue LoadError
          Rack::Handler::WEBrick
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
require 'rails/commands'
```

Notice that it will now try Mongrel and if there is an error try for Thin and only then go with Webrick. Now when you type `rails s` we get the behaviour we're after.

Answer (score 1):

In `script/rails` the following works as well:

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)

require 'rack/handler'
Rack::Handler::WEBrick = Rack::Handler::Thin

require 'rails/commands'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply install thin, cd to the directory that your app is in and run thin start. Works perfectly here. :)

You can use http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/4/27/using-thin-instead-of-mongrel to change as needed. (Its the one I used)

Comment: As an update,  thin -V start works to mimic the behaviour you usually see when you start the rails server, aka where you see the output in the terminal from each connection.

Comment: that's cool. but there's nothing that makes `rails s` run `thin start`?