# Ruby on Rails and Mac OS Lion super slow! Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, osx-lion, rvm, webrick

The versions that I have installed are as follows:
Ruby 1.9.3 
Rails 3.1.1
Webrick 1.3.1
Xcode 4.2.1

I've used RVM to install ruby on rails and successfully started my app, however it is super slow when navigating from view to view.

Ruby is throwing now errors.

What can this be?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know, what can the errors be?

Comment: would help if you included rails log for one of your requests which you consider too slow

Comment: How much slower? Maybe ipv6 dns issue?

Comment: I also run the same app on another machine with same versions... Only difference is xcode 3.2.6 and Snow Leopard.. This may where the problem is.. I'll get those logs up as soon as i can.

Comment: try a different web server. Thin for example. I experienced some serious slowness with webrick but then it was on a very old machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help anyone else with this issue.. What I did was simply switched my server to Mongrel. This did the trick.

[Instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853393/is-there-a-way-rails-3-0-x-can-default-to-using-thin)