# Override Prompt when starting new rail blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I enter

```
    rails new blog
```

it returns

```
    exist  
       identical  README.rdoc
       identical  Rakefile
       identical  config.ru
       identical  .gitignore
       identical  Gemfile
           exist  app
       identical  app/assets/images/rails.png
       identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
       identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
       identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
       identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
           exist  app/mailers
           exist  app/models
       identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
       identical  app/mailers/.gitkeep
       identical  app/models/.gitkeep
           exist  config
       identical  config/routes.rb
       identical  config/application.rb
       identical  config/environment.rb
           exist  config/environments
       identical  config/environments/development.rb
       identical  config/environments/production.rb
       identical  config/environments/test.rb
           exist  config/initializers
       identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
       identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
       identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
        conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
    Overwrite /Users/user/blog/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help)    [Ynaqdh]
```

and whether I hit y/ yes or n/ no it installs the bundle, and the

```
    cd blog
```

command goes through- but then when I try

```
    rails server
```

I get

```
    [2012-06-06 19:21:59] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set     content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

[2012-06-06 19:22:00] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

I found somewhere you are supposed to install "thin" gemfile to fix this, and run

```
    rails server thin
```

and that returns

```
    /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:269:in `server'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

but then the " localhost :3000 " displays an Oops page saying it cant find the page, however when i enter the regular server command the page is intact but the warning prevents me from going any further.

any ideas?

Thank you Dty- Note for n00bs, you need to run server and code in separate windows (I feel slow now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings you see while using `rails server` is normal. Notice they're just **warnings** so there shouldn't be anything stopping you from going any further.

If you use the thin server then the correct command should be `thin start`. If you're using rails 3.2rc2 then [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538244/600953),  `rails server` will work if `gem 'thin'` is in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: That warning doesn't look *normal* to me.

Comment: If you've used rails 3 with asset pipeline you're used to it. See this blog entry for example http://thechangelog.com/post/21217781637/quiet-assets-silence-asset-pipeline-messages

Comment: Are you trying to enter code in the same window that you're running `rails server`? If so, you need to do those in two separate terminal windows. Open two terminal windows, change to the same project directory. In one run `rails server`, in the other write your code.